# Puma caught this error: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, puma, chewy-gem

Puma caught this error: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) with elastic search services use.
when  record update then this issue

ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:105:in `block in records_for' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:361:in` init_with_attributes'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:403:in `instantiate_instance_of' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:61:in` block (2 levels) in find_by_sql'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/result.rb:62:in `block in each' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/result.rb:62:in` each'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/result.rb:62:in `each' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:61:in` map'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:61:in `block in find_by_sql' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in` instrument'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:56:in `find_by_sql' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:821:in` block in exec_queries'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:839:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:808:in` exec_queries'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:626:in `load' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:102:in` records_for'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:41:in `preloaded_records' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:32:in` records_by_owner'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:18:in `block in run' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:17:in` each'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:17:in `run' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:145:in` block in preloaders_for_reflection'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:144:in `each' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:144:in` map'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:144:in `preloaders_for_reflection' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:113:in` block (2 levels) in preloaders_for_hash'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:112:in `each' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:112:in` flat_map'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:112:in `block in preloaders_for_hash' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:111:in` each'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:111:in `flat_map' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:111:in` preloaders_for_hash'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:102:in `preloaders_on' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:92:in` block in preload'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:91:in `each' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:91:in` flat_map'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:91:in `preload' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:745:in` block in preload_associations'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:743:in `each' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:743:in` preload_associations'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:824:in `block in exec_queries' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:839:in` skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:808:in `exec_queries' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:626:in` load'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:250:in `records' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:87:in` each'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/adapter/orm.rb:129:in `block in import_objects' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/adapter/orm.rb:119:in` each'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/adapter/orm.rb:119:in `each_slice' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/adapter/orm.rb:119:in` each'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/adapter/orm.rb:119:in `map' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/adapter/orm.rb:119:in` import_objects'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/adapter/orm.rb:81:in `import' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/import.rb:142:in` block in import_linear'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in` instrument'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/import.rb:141:in` import_linear'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/import.rb:136:in `import_routine' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/type/import.rb:87:in` import!'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/strategy/atomic.rb:25:in `block in leave' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/strategy/atomic.rb:25:in` each'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/strategy/atomic.rb:25:in `all?' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/strategy/atomic.rb:25:in` leave'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/strategy.rb:63:in `tap' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/strategy.rb:63:in` pop'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/strategy.rb:72:in `wrap' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy.rb:201:in` strategy'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/bundler/gems/chewy-c91c6842b3e4/lib/chewy/railtie.rb:19:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in` call_app'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in` block in tagged'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in` tagged'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in` call'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in` call'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in` call'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in` call'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in` call'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in` perform_request'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in` call'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/puma-5.1.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:246:in `call' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/puma-5.1.0/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in` block in handle_request'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/puma-5.1.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/puma-5.1.0/lib/puma/request.rb:75:in` handle_request'
ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/puma-5.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:431:in `process_client' ruby-2.7.2/rails-6.0.3.4/gems/puma-5.1.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in` block in spawn_thread'

Comment: This isn't a Puma error, Puma just reported an error that occurred in the code you asked iy to execute... You should look at the code where the error actually occurred - which your question doesn't include.

Comment: check your elastic search.rb some this is may be occurring there